# Equality relations in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, equals, equality, scala-collections

I just stumbled on one of Tony Morris' [blog-posts about Java](http://blog.tmorris.net/have-you-ever-wanted-to-do-this/) and a fundamental problem with the language: that of defining a bespoke equality-relation for a collection. This is something that I think is a *big deal* and wondered whether there was some scala solution.

The classic issue manifests itself in thinking about, say, a trade.  Let's say I make two trades of +100 vodafone shares @150p. The two trades are equal, yes? Except they are not *the same trade*. In the case of a normal real-world system, with persistence or serialization, I cannot rely on *identity* to tell me whether two references are to *the same trade*!

So what I want is to be able to create a collection which I can pass an Equality-relation to:

```
val as = CleverSet[Trade](IdEquality)
val bs = CleverSet[Trade](EconomicsEquality)
```

How would I implement my set in an efficient manner (unless the `EqualityRelation` also defines a `hash` mechanism)?

```
trait EqualityRelation[T] {
  def equal(t1: T, t2: T) : Boolean
  def hash(t: T) : Int
}
```

So the questions are:

- Is there a library which provides this ability?
- Is there some way of doing this neatly in Scala?

It seems that with implicits, it would be quite an easy thing to add to the existing scala `Set` type.

Comment: There's Equal in Scalaz: http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/ExampleEqual.scala. But I'm not familiar enough to say what builds on it.

Comment: I think that's just a typesafe equals, so that `"Hello" === 2` does not compile

Comment: scalaz.Equal is not just type safe, it's also a flexible. `Equal[List[Foo]]]` is parameterisable by an `Equal[Foo]`. This goes half-way towards your goal. Martin Odersky declined to add `Hash[T]` to the standard library, saying that "we want to maintain universal hashing, it's too much part of
the Java culture." http://www.scala-lang.org/node/4091#comment-16327

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can already be achieved with Java's TreeSet and a Comparator implementation:

```
TreeSet<String> ignoreCase = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
    }});

TreeSet<String> withCase = new TreeSet<String>();

List<String> values = asList("A", "a");
ignoreCase.addAll(values);
withCase.addAll(values);
```

Output:

```
ignoreCase -> [A]
withCase -> [A, a]
```

This has the drawbacks that the Comparator to implement is more powerful than needed and that you're restricted to collections that support Comparators. As pointed out by oxbow_lakes the Comparator implementation breaks the Set contract (for `!a.equals(b)` it could be that `new Set(); set.add(a) == true && set.add(b) == false`).

Scala supports this with a view transformation from A => Ordered[A].

```
scala> new scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[String]()(x=> x.toLowerCase) + "a"
 + "A"
res0: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[String] = Set(A)
```

Comment: And you are forced down the route of the O(log(n)) access time of a tree structure

Comment: Also, from the JavaDoc of `TreeSet`: *Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface*, so it seems that whilst this approach works, it doesn't quite feel right

Comment: This is a valid point. Breaking the Set contract is a bad idea. If you hand this TreeSet around it has to be wrapped. The CleverSet you suggested would break it in the same way. It could only implement Iterable[T] not Set[T].

Comment: only because `Set` is defined in terms of equal. Oh, how I wish it had been defined in terms of a (pluggable) equality relation

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - If you go down this road (flexibility) there will only be getClass left on the java.lang.Object interface.

Comment: @ThomasJung Sounds like an improvement ;)

Answer (score 3):

I know you're asking about Scala, but it's worth comparing with what the .Net collections offer.  In particular, all Hash-based collections (eg `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `HashSet<T>`) can take an instance of [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx). This is similar to Scala's [`Equiv[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Equiv.html), but also supplies a custom hash code.  You could create a similar trait by subclassing `Equiv`:

```
trait HashEquiv[T] extends Equiv[T] {
  def hashOf(t: T) : Int
}
```

To be fully supported, hash based collections would need to add `HashEquiv` implicit parameters to their construction and use the implicitly imported `equiv` and `hashOf` methods instead of the `Object` instance methods (like `TreeSet`, etc do with the `Ordered` trait, but in reverse).  There would also need to be an implicit conversion from `Any` to `HashEquiv` that uses the intrinsic `equals` and `hashCode` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing the concept of a hashing strategy.  The [Trove library](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/) includes sets and maps that can be constructed with hashing strategies.