# Can I create a collection in Scala that uses different equals/hashCode/compare implementations?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm looking for as simple way to create an identity set.  I just want to be able to keep track of whether or not I've "seen" a particular object while traversing a graph.

I can't use a regular Set because Set uses "==" (the equals method in Scala) to compare elements.  What I want is a Set that uses "eq."

Is there any way to create a Set in Scala that uses some application-specified method for testing equality rather than calling equals on the set elements?  I looked for some kind of "wrapEquals" method that I could override but did not find it.

I know that I could use Java's IdentityHashMap, but I'm looking for something more general-purpose.

Another idea I had was to just wrap each set element in another object that implements equals in terms of eq, but it's wasteful to generate tons of new objects just to get a new equals implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341672/equality-relations-in-scala) is a similar question. The accepted answer in that case was to use a `TreeSet` and provide a custom `Comparator`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs you could create a box for which you use identity checks on the contained element such as:

```
class IdentBox[T <: AnyRef](val value: T) {

    override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
      case that: IdentBox[T] => that.value eq this.value
      case _ => false
    }

    override def hashCode(): Int = value.hashCode

  }
```

And make the collection to contain those boxes instead of the elements directly: Set[IdentBox[T]]

It has some overhead of boxing / unboxing but it might be tolerable in your use case.

Comment: The `hashCode` you have provided works (actually any hash would work as long as it returns the same value for the same instance), but perhaps `System.identityHashCode(value)` would work better?

Comment: I am unsure about this given the comment by Willis Blackburn in another answer of this question: Unfortunately System.identityHashCode returns the default hash code value, not the address, so two different objects can have the same identityHashCode value.

Comment: The `identityHashCode` is a 32b bit value (`int`), therefore it is not (and cannot be) guaranteed to be unique on 64b JVM. Still, it is most likely more unique than a `hashValue` which was designed to cooperate with the `case class` value equality, which is what you are using now. In your case anything works, as you would not use `identityHashCode` to perform the comparison, only to serve as a hash to accompany `eq` based comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't require a reference to the "seen" objects, but just a boolean value for "contains", I would suggest just using a `mutable.Set[Int]` and loading it with values obtained by calling `System.identityHashCode(obj)`.

Scala custom collections have enough conceptual surface area to scare off most people who want a quick tweak like this.

Comment: Unfortunately System.identityHashCode returns the default hash code value, not the address, so two different objects can have the same identityHashCode value.  It might work in a 32-bit JVM, but in a 64-bit JVM, there would have to be some clashes.

Comment: This is only a problem if you want your software to work _every_ time. :-)