# How to check, that seq contains another seq with only one field check(not equals/hashcode)

Tags: scala

I need check sequence contains another sequence, but based on one field only:

```
case class Test(f1: Int, f2: String)

val seq = Seq(Test(1, "a"), Test(2, "b"), Test(3, "a"), Test(4, "c"))
```

Now i want to have something like(theoretical not working code):

```
seq.containsSlice(Seq(Test(2, _), Test(3, _))) shouldBe true
```

Where second field can be any.

My idea - create another class, based on `Test`, where `equals/hashcode` uses only one field, and convert my `Seq[Test]` to `Seq[TestWithOneField]`. May be there is more elegant and universal solution?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739432/how-to-implement-a-set-with-a-user-defined-equality) can hint you towards a more "universal" solution to custom equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the sequence to obtain a sequence only of the fields you are checking (in this case a sequence of the integers in the `f1` field):

```
seq.map(_.f1).containsSlice(Seq(2,3))
```